# Download pdfs for a specific topic using scrapy or any other tool

Tags: scrapy

How do I go about writing a spider for scrapy which searches and downloads research papers for a topic like "software health management for aerospace".I have read answers for downloading  the pdfs,files or images from any one website.

But can I write a spider or is their any other way of searching the  web for a topic and downloading documents based on that topic from different websites?

Comment: yes, pdf is just like any other page. Try `scrapy shell http://example.com/file.pdf` and check `response.body` you'll see that the whole pdf content is in the there so you can save it as a .pdf file and it will be quivalent to downloading it.

Comment: Try writing a spider that finds the URLs of the PDFs first, then update your question.